# How to decode a tensor into base64 in TensorflowJs?

Tags: react-native, base64, decode, tensor, tensorflow.js

I'm developing a react native application where I use TensorflowJs. I'm using `cameraWithTensors` from `tfjs-react-native` package which gives me images as Tensors of type `int32`. I want to convert those tensor data into base64 so I can render it in the app.

Somehow I found a solution to convert base64 data into tensor as shown below but I cannot do the opposite. I found `decodJpeg` method tfjs docs but it's **opposite is not available**. I tried many solutions but none of them worked.

```
URItoTensor = async URI => {
        const imgB64 = await FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(URI, {
            encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.Base64,
        });
        const imgBuffer = tf.util.encodeString(imgB64, 'base64').buffer;
        const unit8 = new Uint8Array(imgBuffer)
        const tensor = decodeJpeg(unit8);
        return tensor;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [toPixels](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#browser.toPixels) to convert the tensor to a canvas and then use `canvas.toDataURL` to get the base64 encoding

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = tensor.shape.width
canvas.height = tensor.shape.height
await tf.browser.toPixels(tensor, canvas);
canvas.toDataURL() // will return the base64 encoding
```

The above will work in the browser but not in react-native. React-native has `binaryToBase64` to convert from a typedarray;

```
const bytes = tensor.dataSync(); // can also use the async .data
const encoded = binaryToBase64(bytes); // base64 string
```

**Update**

`encodeString` is not the method to be used to convert a base64 to a tensor whose underline representation is an image. EncodeString only encode a string as a typedArray. Here is the way to load an image to a tensor. There is even no need to use a base64 string before.

```
// Load an image as a Uint8Array
const response = await fetch('path/of/image', {}, { isBinary: true });
const imageDataArrayBuffer = await response.arrayBuffer();
cosnt imageData = new Uint8Array(imageDataArrayBuffer);

// Decode image data to a tensor
const tensor = decodeJpeg(imageData);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but It doesn't work because the variable `document` doesn't work with React Native. I'm developing a mobile application. Can you help me with this?

Comment: No ! that doesn't work as well ... so tired of this thing. I just want to display my images in my app.

Comment: Not an error but the encoded base64 doesn't show anything when I pass as an uri in the  source of Image class. In my code above, when I convert unit8 array back to base64, it works again well but not the tensor after decodJpeg method.

Comment: Could it be that you need to append  `"data:image/png;base64,"` at the beginning of the decoded string? Have you tried to use `tf.decodeString (bytes, 'base64')` as well ?

Comment: Yes ! I tried every solution but none of them worked. I cross checked the original arrays and base64 and converted arrays and base64 respectively but they are different. I tried to append data:image.... with png, jpg, jpeg and all, it won't work still which is very disappointing. I even tried to reverse decodeJpeg method :(

Comment: If you are to transform an image to a tensor, there is no need to transform it first to a base64. See my edited answer

Comment: He did not want that, he wanted to convert the tensors to base64 so that they can be displayed.